# Parse CSV data for SQL Insert Query Using Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, make.com

I need help with some Regex, please. I'm trying to use Integromat to get some data, then parse it into a format suitable for a SQL INSERT command. Integromat uses Javascript regex.

The initial data looks like this:

```
Identifier,Handle,Type
CS18511,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
CS185110231,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
CS185110232,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
CS185110233,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
```

I want to apply regex substitution to achieve this format, ideally without the heading row.

```
('CS18511','big-3-jersey,men''s' jerseys'),
('CS185110231','big-3-jersey,men''s jerseys'),
('CS185110232','big-3-jersey,men''s jerseys'),
('CS185110233','big-3-jersey,men''s jerseys')
```

I've tried the below, which seems to group the items I want, but can't find a substitution that works to create the desired output.

`((?=[^\s,])(?: ?[^[\s,]+|\[[^]]*])*|(?<=,|^)(?=\s*(?:,|$)))`

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Why???? You can insert the data directly with [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example on how to use `BULK INSERT`

```
Create Table #YourTable (Identifier varchar(50),Handle varchar(50),Type varchar(50))
Bulk Insert  #YourTable FROM 'C:\Working\MyData.csv' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2,
                                                            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
                                                            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
                                                          )
Select * from #YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Identifier   Handle         Type
CS18511      big-3-jersey   men's jerseys
CS185110231  big-3-jersey   men's jerseys
CS185110232  big-3-jersey   men's jerseys
CS185110233  big-3-jersey   men's jerseys
```

Comment: Many thanks John... I wasn't aware of bulk insert. Unfortunately, the CSV data is created dynamically via an API call to our PIM, so it's not a physical file with a location to reference.

Comment: This is the failed output:

`CREATE TABLE PIM_DATA
(
    Identifier VARCHAR(100),
    Handle VARCHAR(100),
    Type VARCHAR(100)
 )
END
BEGIN
BULK INSERT PIM_DATA FROM '"Identifier,Handle,Shopify Type
CS18511,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
CS185110231,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
CS185110232,big-3-jersey,men's jerseys
etc...`

Comment: @tbizzlebozzle  bulk insert is assume a source file.